# AFNetworking 2.0 adds [] square brackets to json that get send to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 and have run into a problem.

I am trying to PUT an array in json to the server.

I am posting the Array like (See Code Below). I am adding the following array to the Json params to send to the server:

```
themes =     (
    "Fashion - Men",
    Kids,
    "Styling / Hair"
);
```

and this gets send to the server:

```
{
id = 654;
tags = test;
themes =     (
    "Fashion - Men",
    Kids,
    "Styling / Hair"
);
```

}

However the server receives the json like so WHICH IS WRONG:

```
{'id': '654', 'themes[]': ['Kids', 'Styling / Hair', 'Accessories - Women'], 'tags': 'test'}
```

AFNetworking is putting [] square brackets by themes in the sent json like themes[] so the cal is right except for this:themes[]

Have no idea how to fix this.

```
- (void) piccMedia: (NSString*) aPiccId Tags: (NSString *) aTags Themes: (NSMutableArray *) anThemes
           success:(void (^)(NSArray *response))success
           failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{

    NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject: @"654" forKey:@"id"];
    [params setObject: aTags forKey:@"tags"];
    [params setObject: anThemes forKey:@"themes"];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *piccingAuthToken = [prefs stringForKey:@"piccingAuthToken"];
    NSString *piccingUsername = [prefs stringForKey:@"piccingUsername"];
    NSLog(@"piccingAuthToken %@ %@", piccingAuthToken,piccingUsername);

    NSString *postQueryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dev.com/services/rest/profiles/%@/media",piccingUsername];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [JSONResponseSerializerWithData serializer];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/plain", @"text/html", nil];
    manager.responseSerializer = [JSONResponseSerializerWithData serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:piccingAuthToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-authtoken"];

    [manager PUT:postQueryString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        success(responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        id json = error.userInfo [JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey];
        failure(json);
    }];
}

 2014-02-24 16:49:25.265 App[7314:70b] JSON Parameters{
id = 654;
tags = test;
themes =     (
    "Accessories - Women",
    "Styling / Hair",
    Kids
);
}
```

Comment: `NSLog` params and add the output to your answer.

Comment: `params can more easily be created: `NSDictionary *params = @{ @"id":@"654", @"tags":aTags, @"themes":anThemes};`

Comment: What is `JSONResponseSerializerWithData`? That doesn't come with AFNetworking.  Can you post the code of it?

Comment: JSONResponseSerializerWithData just helps me explain my error better

Comment: Oh sorry. JSONResponseSerializerWithData does come with AFNetworking

Comment: No. JSONResponseSerializerWithData does not come with AFNetworking.

Comment: set yout parameter encoding type to jsonEncoding

Comment: How do you know what the server receives? Did you examine the transmission with a network analyzer such as Charles Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You should set requestSerializer to `AFJSONRequestSerializer`

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```